# creating a temp table inside an IF clause

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Inside a stored procedure:

```
IF (condition1)
     SELECT * INTO #temp FROM table1 WHERE name = 'Dave'
ELSE
     SELECT * INTO #temp FROM table1 WHERE name = 'Greg'
```

When creating the stored procedure, it says "There is already an object named '#temp' in the database".   It must think I am creating the same temp table twice.

Is there a good way around it ?

I know I can do INSERT INTO #temp (....), 
but there are a lot of fields and I don't want to retype them.

Comment: make sure there is no table in database called #temp.. or use drop table before select statement.

Comment: The error happens at compile time.  It wouldn't even create the sproc.  It thinks I am creating #temp twice.

Comment: i believe if you do a check before select statement like (if #temp not exist than) it will not get break.

Answer (score 2):

If this is silly don't -1
Just let me know and I will delete
I don't know the nature of your condition1

by why not?

```
SELECT * INTO #temp 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE ( condition1 and name = 'Dave')
    OR (!condition1 and name = 'Greg')
```

Comment: I don't think it is silly.  In fact, this is probably the best solution.  Unfortunately, it may not work "real world".  Looks like the sample code is a made up example for the purpose of the question.  In reality, the condition may be much more complicated or the source table (table1 in this example) may not be the same for each condition.

Comment: @GMastros But if I had just asked for clarification on condition1 the OP may not have understood the question.

Comment: It can be done.   But, in my case at least, it has noticeable performance consequences.  I ended up just creating a temp table first and then doing INSERT INTO.

Comment: Are you evaluating a complex condition1 many times?  Try evaluate it once and assign it to a variable and reference the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM table1 WHERE 1 = 0

IF (condition1)
     INSERT INTO #temp SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name = 'Dave'
ELSE
     INSERT INTO #temp SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name = 'Greg'
```

The select into will not return any rows, but it will make the temp table with the correct columns.

Comment: That would work.   But it creates the overhead of the first SELECT.  Also, I would do SELECT TOP 0 * INTO #temp FROM table1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
     If (condition1)
        INSERT INTO #temp 
          SELECT * FROM table1 where name = 'Dave'
     ELSE
        INSERT INTO #temp 
       SELECT * FROM table1 where name = 'Greg'
```

Comment: This will give you "Invalid object name '#temp'.
You must create the temp table first.
But I don't want to because it has a lot of fields.